# Getting the bounds when drawing on the canvas in android

Tags: android

I am drawing a Drawable to a custom view in android.

When the custom view is displayed the parent is a ScrollView. When the scrollview moves the Drawables shrink until they get off screen and then get bigger as you scroll back to the custom widget even though its explicitly set at 219dip square.

The reason seems to be the way I'm getting the bounds in the onDraw(Canvas canvas) method

```
    int mRight;
    int mLeft;
    int mBottom;
    int mTop;

    mRight = canvas.getClipBounds().right; 
    mLeft = canvas.getClipBounds().left;
    mBottom = canvas.getClipBounds().bottom;
    mTop = canvas.getClipBounds().top;

    int availableWidth = mRight - mLeft;
    int availableHeight = mBottom - mTop;
```

It seems that the ClipBound changes to reflect how much of the view is on the screen. Therefore resize the Drawables until it gets really small and goes off screen.

I tried to replace the code above with this

```
    int availableWidth = canvas.getWidth();
    int availableHeight = canvas.getHeight();
```

Nothing is drawn to the screen now? shouldn't this work?

Comment: Any luck getting this working?

Comment: yep I thought i'd posted the correct answer I'll do it now!

Answer (score 4):

When drawing my custom Drawable I use:

```
float w = this.getBounds().width();
float h = this.getBounds().height();
```

to get the bounding area of the my Drawable in the `draw(Canvas canvas)`method.  I have not tried this in a ScrollView, but I would think that the bounds of the Drawable should work the same either way.

Hope this helps.

Comment: I'll give it a try when I get home tonight, thanks for the heads up.

Answer (score 4):

This works for my custom View, this code goes in the onDraw(Canvas canvas) method.

```
    mRight = this.getRight();
    mLeft = this.getLeft();
    mBottom = this.getBottom();
    mTop = this.getTop();

    int availableWidth = mRight - mLeft;
    int availableHeight = mBottom - mTop;
```

previous answer was wrong, view has no method getBounds()

Comment: I state in my answer that mine is a custom Drawable, not a view.  That is why it is different...  same idea though.  Glad you got it.

Comment: I think you can just use `getWidth()` and `getHeight()` instead of calculating it yourself.